# Select data from a db, concatenate them, write to a file and get it cut

Tags: php

I've some data in MySql database. Frankly speaking, it is a database for a WordPress project.

Anyway, I selected 264 rows from the database and concatenate them:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(alias.d) as selection from (SELECT quote(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y')) as d FROM wp_ved_currencies where char_code="USD" order by date desc limit 264) as alias
```

Date is just the date type.

I tried execute the command in phpMyAdmin and copy the value. Then I tried to export the value as Json also in phpMyAdmin. And I tried to organize writing to an error_log like this:

```
error_log($wpdb->get_results("select GROUP_CONCAT(alias.d) as selection from (SELECT quote(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y')) as d FROM wp_ved_currencies where char_code=\"USD\" order by date desc limit 264) as alias")[0]->selection, 3, "test.log")
```

The problem is that everything is cut at the same place. The length of the string is 1024 symbols. Well, it is not the biggest string in the world. Francly speaking, I need it saved automatically. So, error_log is the preferrable method.

Could you help me here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` has a [maximum length of 1024 characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). You either need to change the upper bounds of that setting for MySQL, or just stage your data into an array and remove the `GROUP_CONCAT` from the equation.

Comment: Thank you. If you organize it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` has a [maximum length of 1024 characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). You either need to change the upper bounds of that setting for MySQL, or just stage your data into an array and remove the `GROUP_CONCAT` from the equation.

I have hit this quite a few times...